# Aggregate sum of multiple columns by date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-munging

My df looks like this

| Date | Col | Col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | A | 500 |
| 01/01/2022 | B | 100 |
| 01/01/2022 | C | 400 |
| 02/01/2022 | A | 400 |
| 02/01/2022 | B | 150 |
| 02/01/2022 | C | 450 |

My desired output looks like

| Date | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1000 |
| 02/01/2022 | 1000 |

Please help. I wanna do it automatically (not manually-hardcoded)

I am trying this

```
df.groupby('Date')['Col1'].sum()
```

Comment: did it not work? what's the problem?

Comment: @enke I didn't get the output which I expected my output is still same as my df

Comment: Then your date column consists of all unique dates.

Comment: out = df.groupby('Date')['Col1'].sum()

print(out)

Comment: @BENY it gives me only two columns Date and Col1. What if I have say 10 columns ?

Comment: So do you want to be able to sum across multiple columns and multiple rows for a specific date?

Comment: I suggest you can change the titile to : Aggregate sum of multiple columns by date in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just summing the entire group, rather than a specific column:

```
df.groupby('Date').sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need totals and the separate column values for a given date, follow this general format.

```
needed_columnms = ['List','Of','Needed','Columns']
df_sums = df.groupby('Date')[needed_columns].sum()
df_sums['Total'] = df_sums[needed_columns].sum(1)
```

df_sums will provide you with a column total and grand total for each of the dates within 'Date'.